# How to use buttons in MVC for different purposes

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I do have three buttons in my view. So now I want two buttons to post back and the third button to perform some jquery. How to do this. Like how to make the third button not to post back and perform some  jquery actions.
Thanks

Comment: Please add you code of cshtml page, because i want to see which method are you using for postback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In HTML the tag `button` has the attibute `type`:

To post back data (submit a form) you must set `type` to `submit` (this is default value, so you may drop the `type` attribute at all).

To perform some javascript actions you must set `type` to `button`.

In two different submit buttoms use same `name` and different `values`:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Login", "Home")
{
    <label for="login">Login:</label>
    @Html.TextBox("login", Model.Login)

    <label for="password">Password:</label>
    @Html.Password("password", "")

    <button type="submit" name="what" value="login">Log in</button>
    <button type="submit" name="what" value="register">Register</button>
    <button type="button" id="facebook">Facebook authentication</button>
}

<script>
$(function() {
    // Perform jquery action.
    $('#facebook').click(...);
});
</script>
```

In controller:

```
public ActionResult Login(string login, string password, string what)
{
    if (what == "login")
        . . .
    else if (what == "register")
        return RedirectToAction("Register", "Home");
}
```

Comment: so great of you I got it know. I am new to both i.e; new to programming and new on stackoverflow. Thanks a lot. Regards

Answer (score 3):

You can do this like

```
<form id="myForm">
    <%-- form data inputs here ---%>
    <button id="Postback">Postback</button>
    <button id="JavaScript">JavaScript</button>
</form>
```

and in javascript

```
<script type="text/javascript">
      $("#Postback").click(function() {
          var form = $("form#myForm");
          form.attr("action", "@Url.Action("action","MyController")");
          form.submit();
      });

      $("#JavaScript").click(function() {
         Do your javascript something.
      });
</script>
```

Comment: @Mohammed Please tick the answer which is help full to you as an answer.

Comment: Both are useful to me As I am new to stackoverflow I don't have enough privileges to do so. Sorry for that. However thx a lot for your wonderful answer.

Comment: @Mohammed you can do this.
To mark an answer as accepted, click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.

Please check this link http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work